# Typescript allows passing non-undefined values for undefined parameter

Tags: typescript

I tried the following code in typescript playground with all options turned on.
I expect TS compiler to allow only first `call()` to be valid. However all four are.

By hovering over calls I see them typed as `call<"String"|undefined>`.
What's going on here? Is there any way to force this check?

```
interface IEndpoint<RequestType> { }
export const GetConsumer: IEndpoint<undefined> = {};
function call<RequestType>(rpc: IEndpoint<RequestType>, request: RequestType) {}

call(GetConsumer, undefined);
call(GetConsumer, null); // should not be allowed
call(GetConsumer, 1); // should not be allowed
call(GetConsumer, "String");  // should not be allowed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the typescript [specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#327-the-undefined-type)

> The undefined type is a subtype of all types. This means that undefined is considered a valid value for all primitive types, object types, union types, intersection types, and type parameters.

Let's consider how typescript would resolve the following scenario:

```
class Base{ b: number}
class Derived extends Base{ c: number}
let GetDerived: IEndpoint<Derived>;
call(GetConsumer, new Base());
```

There are two possible types for the generic parameter `RequestType` in `call`: `Derived` (based on the first parameter) and `Base` (based on the second parameter). Typescript will choose the common base type for the two, so `RequestType` will be `Base`.

Now lets consider one of your examples:

```
call(GetConsumer, 1);
```

Similarly to the first example, `RequestType` in `call` can be: `undefined` (based on the first parameter) and `number` (based on the second parameter for example). Since `undefined` in a subtype of all types it is also a subtype of number, so the best common base type is `number`.

If you are looking for a type that would not allow the last two calls, `void` could do that since:

> The only possible values for the Void type are null and undefined. The Void type is a subtype of the Any type and a supertype of the Null and Undefined types, but otherwise Void is unrelated to all other types.

```
export const GetConsumer: IEndpoint<void> = {

};
call(GetConsumer, undefined);//still ok 
call(GetConsumer, null); // still ok 
call(GetConsumer, 1); // error
call(GetConsumer, "String");  // error
```